# Curl and divergence

Tags: differentiation, vector-fields

I am trying to understand  curl and divergences in a more intuitive manner, especially the curl. And is curl a surface phenomenon, if yes then how?

Comment: More on [differentiation of vector fields](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differentiation+vector-fields).

Comment: You should probably first read the Wikipedia articles on curl and divergence where  intuitive explanations for these operators on vector fields are given. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence

Answer (score 0):

[A discussion on the intuitive interpretation of the curl from math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15166/could-you-a-give-a-intutive-interpretation-of-curl). And a quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)):

> If the vector field represents the flow velocity of a moving fluid, then the curl is the circulation density of the fluid.

For divergence, I'd also point you to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence):

> More technically, the divergence represents the volume density of the outward flux of a vector field from an infinitesimal volume around a given point.
>   As an example, consider air as it is heated or cooled. The velocity of the air at each point defines a vector field. While air is heated in a region, it expands in all directions, and thus the velocity field points outward from that region. The divergence of the velocity field in that region would thus have a positive value. While the air is cooled and thus contracting, the divergence of the velocity has a negative value.

I know, it's a lot of quotes and links, but there's nothing new under the sun ;)